# How to get the value of a variable to a string?

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a `item` to my `listView`.  The `listView` populates but I am getting this:

> Systems.Collection.Generic.List'1[System.String]

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
foreach (SearchResult entry in result)
        {
            var members = GetGroupMemberList(entry.GetDirectoryEntry());
            var item = members;
            itmListItem = new ListViewItem((string)entry.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]);
            itmListItem.SubItems.Add(item.ToString());
            lvwListView.Items.Add(itmListItem);
            lvwListView.Refresh();
            itmListItem = null;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Since `members` is a list, did you want to add each item in that list to `SubItems`? Maybe like `foreach(var item in members)` instead of `var item = members`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that `item` is not a `string`: it's a `List<string>`, so calling `ToString()` on it doesn't show you anything more meaningful than its type. Often people really want to get something like a comma-separated list of items to show, which could be accomplished by saying `string.Join(", ", members)`.

But I'm reading the tea leaves here and thinking you probably really want each `item` in the `members` to show up as a sub-item in your list, which you could accomplish like this:

```
    foreach (SearchResult entry in result)
    {
        var members = GetGroupMemberList(entry.GetDirectoryEntry());
        foreach(var item in members)
        {
            var itmListItem = new ListViewItem((string)entry.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]);
            itmListItem.SubItems.Add(item.ToString());
            lvwListView.Items.Add(itmListItem);
        }
        lvwListView.Refresh();
    }
```

Note that I'm declaring `itmListItem` closer to where you actually use it, which makes it unnecessary to set it to `null` later. It's generally good practice to declare variables closer to their usage, and in as small as scope as possible.